# Python: How to apply a function to a column based on values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to run a currency conversion function on a table so that if the currency in the each row isn't already in the converted currency it changes it. I am using pandas, and have looked into the docs on numpy but have not been able to solve the issue.

So far I have this:

```
    price   currency
0   11184.86    EUR
1   17277.48    PLN
2   26273.80    XOF
3   86425.94    BRL
4   7179.07     KGS
... ... ...
995 34489.28    PHP
996 35062.02    CNY
997 73420.41    PHP
998 94584.51    CNY
999 84047.74    KWD
```

I'm trying to add a column for the converted currency using a function that converts all currencies based on the currency input. For example if I choose EUR then row one would have a None value in the new column but the other non-EUR rows would be converted. The function I'm using need the following:

```
converter(current_currency, conv_currency, ammount)
```

So I'm trying to create and extra column that takes the value of currency column and price column and generates the new column like so:

```
    price   currency   f'currency({conv_currency})'
0   11184.86    EUR
1   17277.48    PLN
2   26273.80    XOF
3   86425.94    BRL
4   7179.07     KGS
... ... ...
995 34489.28    PHP
996 35062.02    CNY
997 73420.41    PHP
998 94584.51    CNY
999 84047.74    KWD
```

I've been using this to try get it to work but I don't know where to go from here:

```
df[f'currency({conv_currency})] 
df.loc[df["currency"] != currency, f'currency({conv_currency})'] = df['price'].map()
```

EDIT:

I've been working on it for a little and this is how far I've gotten but I'm struggling to extract the current currency to plug into the method.

```
df[f'conv currency ({conv_cur})'] = df.loc[df['currency'] != conv_cur]['price'].map(lambda x: cc.convert(still_need_this_value, conv_cur, x))
```

Comment: would be pretty simple if you used `map` where are your conversion rates?

Comment: https://data-flair.training/blogs/currency-converter-python/

I'm using this without the tkinter stuff

Comment: "I choose EUR then row one would have a None value in the new column but the other non-EUR rows would be converted" `Special cases aren't special enough`. Why not just do the currency conversion anyway? I would expect `11184.86` EUR in EUR to give `11184.86`, not `NaN`. Does the `converter` function not handle that for some reason?

Comment: Think about the logic. For a given input from the `df['price']` column - let's call it `p` - and a given input from the`df['currency']` column - let's call it `c` - what is the call that gives us the output value fro the new cell? `converter(c, conv_currency, p)`, right? We can't just `.map` a Series, because there are two Series that we want to use as inputs. So, how about [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the entire DataFrame?

Comment: That is something I could change easily and did bring up to another person working on their own version, but isn't really relevant to the core issue I'm having which is getting the currency column value for my map function. (Relpy to first comment)

Comment: I think there is probably a duplicate for this question, but I am not a Pandas expert and don't have one handy, so I just took my best shot at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both columns are needed as input, we can't expect to just map a `Series` - we'd need to get corresponding values from the other column, and as you've noted, don't have an obvious way to do that.

Instead, let's `.apply` on the entire DataFrame. Since we want to consider rows, we will use `axis=1`. Then, our function will accept a row of the original, and can access the individual cells via the normal subscripting or attribute access.

The function we want to use simply wraps `converter` to pass the cell values in the appropriate places, along with the hard-coded `conv_currency` which is the same across the entire new column. Finally we can assign those `apply` results to make the new column.

Putting it all together gives something like:

```
df[f'currency({conv_currency})'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: converter(row.currency, conv_currency, row.price),
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Ok I just got to this point and the code all runs thank you for the help. Now I just have to add all the exchange rates that the api didn't have. Once again thank you very much.